# (complete newbie) Configuring Oracle Database failed, Specified SGA size is greater than the shmmax on the system. Please read details bellow

Tags: linux, database, oracle

So, i know little to nothing about setting up an sql server but i am needed to do it. When i start configuring the oracle database though this happens:

The command i entered:

> sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure

The error traceback:

```
/bin/df: unrecognized option '--direct'
Try '/bin/df --help' for more information.
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c: line 446: netstat: command not found
Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
Confirm the password:
Configuring Oracle Listener.
Listener configuration succeeded.
Configuring Oracle Database XE.
[FATAL] [DBT-50000] Unable to check for available memory.
[WARNING] [DBT-11207] Specified SGA size is greater than the shmmax on the system. The database creation might fail with "ORA-27125 - Unable to create shared memory segment error".
   ACTION: Specify SGA size lesser than or equal to the shmmax on the system.

Database configuration failed. Check logs under '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca'.
```

Please tell me what am i supposed to do here

Comment: You need to do what the error tells you: specify SGA size less than SHMAX parameter. Did you try to read the documentation on each of the mentioned parameters?

Comment: What os is this on?  If a Linux (as it appears) exactly what 'flavor' and version?  You should not being doing oracle admin tasks as root (as when you use sudo) but actually logged on as the OS user (not root) that will own and admin the installation.

Comment: @EdStevens I am using xubuntu 20.0.4. I think i understand what you mean. But i am still not sure what am i supposed to do properly.

Comment: Oracle is not even designed to be installed on ubuntu, which is from a completely different branch of the Linux family tree.  The internet has lots of hacks available for getting it installed, but that's all they are -  hacks. And even after a "successful" install, there are plenty of other things that can fail.  You need to install Oracle VirtualBox on your Ubuntu machine, then use that to create a VM, Install Oracle Linux on that, then install Oracle database there.